# SQL Mask column concat with static string

Tags: sql, data-masking

Concat masked column with static string return masked data.

eg : Select name+ '-IT' from Employee

always return XXXX

i expect result: xxx-IT

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.  Tag your question with an appropriate database.  And explain how an expression with `+ 'IT'` is supposed to return `'XXXX'`.

Comment: `select 'XXXX' from Employee`

Comment: output:  i guess xxxx-IT

Answer (score 0):

Please share more details. This might also help:

```
SELECT CONCAT(name, '-IT') FROM EMPLOYEE
```

Comment: @Surendra which database are you using? What is the error you are getting?